# Folder sharing ubuntu 12 - revoke permissions

Tags: 12.04, samba, shared-folders

I tried setting up a share on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine to my Win7 machine. I right clicked on a folder in Ubuntu and chose the Sharing options and gave it read and write permissions too. Now the problem is, I chose my `Videos` folder to be shared, but when I access it on my windows machine, I can see my whole system! To top it of, it has write permissions too. How do I revoke this and share only that one folder?

I deleted all the shares and tried `smbclient -L localhost` and I got

```
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.3]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (xyz server (Samba, Ubuntu))
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers

Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.3]

Server               Comment
---------            -------
XYZ                xyz server (Samba, Ubuntu)
ABPC            

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            XYZ
```

which lists no shared folders, but I can still access them through my windows machine.

Other things I tried

```
net usershare list (lists nothing)

ls -l /var/lib/samba/usershares (returns total 0)


smbstatus --shares
Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------
IPC$         8888   xyz         Wed Oct 10 21:56:22 2012
Videos       8625   abpc        Wed Oct 10 21:54:22 2012
IPC$         8767   xyz         Wed Oct 10 21:56:17 2012
```

I'm at my wits end. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a reboot was required... **facepalm**